# find the coordinate vector of with respect to a non square basis

Tags: linear-algebra

*Short question :* Does a basis absolutly has to be square to find the coordinate of a vector in it ?

Detailed question :

First, I am asked to find a base for these 3 vectors.

$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 4\\
-2 & 1 & 3\\
1 & 1 & 2\\
3 & -2 & 1\end{array} \right]$

Using Gauss, I found that matrix:

$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 4\\
0 & 3 & 11\\
0 & 0 & -2\\
0 & 0 & 0\end{array} \right]$

my answer : Since I have no free variable, these 3 vectors form a base in $R^4$

Then it says : **If possible, find the coordinates of this vector :** $[2,−1, 2, 1]$

Then, to find out the coordinates of the vector, I went on and made it an augmented matrix.

$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 4 & 2\\
-2 & 1 & 3 & -1\\
1 & 1 & 2 & 2\\
3 & -2 & 1 & 1\end{array} \right]$

Using Gauss, I found out this matrix

$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 4 & 2\\
0 & 3 & 11 & 3\\
0 & 0 & -2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array} \right]$

From here I figured that 
$
x3 = 0\\ x2 = 1 \\ x1 = 1
$

So I decided to do this linear combination to obtains the coordinate

$ 1 \dot\ v1 + 1 \dot\ v2 + 0 \dot\ v3$

I actually went on and computed the above linear combination and it sucessfully gave me [2,-1,2,1]

So final answer : The coordinates are [c1,c2,c3] = [1,1,0]

but my answer is in $R^3$ ? Is this correct ?

Here is my concern : I think the teacher said that I need a square basis to find the coordinates of a vector within it ?

Comment: No free variables implies that the vectors are linearly independent, not that they form a basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to find $3$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ that span $\mathbb{R}^4$ since that would violate the [Dimension Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces).

Any collection of vectors will span a subspace.  In this case there are $3$ linearly independent vectors, so they will be a basis for a $3$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Can you simplify ?

Comment: Hmmm but what if E = { v1, v2 , v3 } , and they ask to find a basis of lin E ? They didnt exactly asked me to find a basis of R4

Comment: You've found the linear combination fine.  But the claim that the three vectors are a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is incorrect.  The notion of a "square" basis matrix will be about $n$-dimension vector spaces represented by bases in which vectors have $n$ components.  It's not true in other cases, e.g. the one you studied, or even more obviously $$\mathrm{span}((1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0)).$$

Comment: Ok I get that. My 3 vectors doesn't form a basis of R4. But it does form a basis for Lin E. Right ? So how about the rest of the problem where I find the coordinates, is this part correct ?

Comment: Well, I haven't checked your arithmetic, but your answer is correct.  You have essentially proved it a second time by checking: "I actually went on and computed the above linear combination and it sucessfully gave me [2,-1,2,1]".